# Spring MVC Path Pattern Matching Doesn't Handle Dashes

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, ant

I have a `@Configuration` class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` with a method similar to this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry r) {
    final Integer CACHE_LONGTERM = 31536000;
    r.addResourceHandler("jQuery-File-Upload*/**").addResourceLocations("/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.3").setCachePeriod(CACHE_LONGTERM);
}
```

When trying to access those static resources Spring does not match the URL (e.g. http://localhost:8080/app/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.3/js/file.js) with the configured resource handler (404 error or similar). If I change the name of the directory on the filesystem though and remove the *initial* dashes from the pattern, then it works (e.g. using http://localhost:8080/app/jQueryFileUpload-9.9.3/js/file.js):

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry r) {
    final Integer CACHE_LONGTERM = 31536000;
    r.addResourceHandler("jQueryFileUpload*/**").addResourceLocations("/jQueryFileUpload-9.9.3").setCachePeriod(CACHE_LONGTERM);
}
```

I've tried to debug this a little bit and can see Spring uses `org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher` in order to process these patterns. The code in that class is pretty messy though and I know Spring has had pattern/path related bugs in the past. Is this another defect? How can I modify the code above so it works without having to remove the dashes as I did in the workaround?

Using Spring 4.1.6 and Java 8.

**UPDATE**

A deleted response suggested "escaping" the dashes somehow. Note, that the following does not work either:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry r) {
    final Integer CACHE_LONGTERM = 31536000;
    r.addResourceHandler("jQuery\\-File\\-Upload*/**").addResourceLocations("/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.3").setCachePeriod(CACHE_LONGTERM);
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps need a leading `/` on `jQueryFileUpload`?

Comment: @beerbajay -- No because there is also not a leading slash on the version that works (the 2nd snippet above). The issue must relate to the dashes.

Comment: Can you put spring in trace and put the logs?

Answer (score 1):

Given the following configuration:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry r) {
  r.addResourceHandler("/resources/foo-*/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
}
```

a request like `GET /app/resources/foo-bar/file.js` will try to resolve the following on disk: `/static/foo-bar/file.js`. Spring is getting the pattern part of the request (given the pattern you've configured) - see  [AntPathMatcher.extractPathWithinPattern](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html#extractPathWithinPattern-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

So in your case I think it's actually trying to resolve `"/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.3/jQuery-File-Upload-9.9.3/js/file.js"`.

I've managed to resolve resources with a `"-"` within the pattern definition.

For additional guidance, turning the LOG level to DEBUG for `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource` should give us more information.

If you manage to isolate and reproduce this issue, please [create a repro project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues) and/or a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR)

Comment: Thanks I will take another look soon and try to do the repro project.